# How do I revise this HTML document to use the DOM 2 Event Model

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom, model

I am confused, I was able to successfully complete the document using DOM 0 Evemt model. I am just not sure how to revises it to meet the DOM 2 Event model standards. I have asked difference tutors from Chegg and they can't figure it out either. Surely someone on here can help me out!:)

P.S.
I have read several different articles such as this one http://cs.loc.edu/~chu/ITEC315/ch5/DOM2.html that talks about DOM2 and even give an example of what a DOM2 event model document looks like. I think it looks pretty similar to DOM 0 but it still not making sense to me. I just need someone to look at my document and really guide me through it and point stuff out. Like "this is how you do what you got here in the DOM2 event model way.

Thank you Drake!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="generator" content="CoffeeCup HTML Editor (www.coffeecup.com)">
    <meta name="dcterms.created" content="Tue, 02 Oct 2018 05:15:54 GMT">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <title>Assignment1 M5A1</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<h4>Pick your favorite color!</h4>
<form id="myform" action="">
<p>
<label>
<input type="radio" name= "ColorButton" value="1" onclick = "Colorchoice(1)"/>
Red

</label>
<br />


<label>
<input type="radio" name= "ColorButton" value="2" onclick = "Colorchoice(2)"/>
Blue

</label>
<br />



<label>
<input type="radio" name= "ColorButton" value="3" onclick = "Colorchoice(3)"/>
Green

</label>
<br />


<label>
<input type="radio" name= "ColorButton" value="4" onclick = "Colorchoice(4)"/>
Yellow

</label>
<br />



<label>
<input type="radio" name= "ColorButton" value="5" onclick = "Colorchoice(5)"/>
Orange

</label>
<br />

</p>


</form>

<script>
function Colorchoice(Color) {

switch(Color){
case 1:
alert("Your favorite color is Red");
break;


case 2:
alert("Your favorite color is Blue");
break;



case 3:
alert("Your favorite color is Green");
break;




case 4:
alert("Your favorite color is Yellow");
break;



case 5:
alert("Your favorite color is Orange");
break;

default:
alert("Error in JavaScript function Colorchoice");
break;
}
}

</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's working...
https://jsfiddle.net/audshwr0/

```
<h4>Pick your favorite color!</h4>
<form id="myform" action="">
<p>
<label>
<input type="radio" name= "ColorButton" value="1" onclick = "Colorchoice(event)"/>
Red

</label>
<br />


<label>
<input type="radio" name= "ColorButton" value="2" onclick = "Colorchoice(event)"/>
Blue

</label>
<br />



<label>
<input type="radio" name= "ColorButton" value="3" onclick = "Colorchoice(event)"/>
Green

</label>

<script>
function Colorchoice(event) {
console.log(event.target.value);
}
</script>
```

Comment: One more small question please I seen you modified my code and now it isn't working. Do I need to add the case statement back?  Again sorry I am so confused with DOM 2 element model. LOL